# Referencing whole class from resource dictionary

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I've created a resource dictionary with multiple classes

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Something_GUI">

    <PathGeometry x:Key="DeleteIcon" Figures="M93.05,47.59A2.08,2.08,0,0,0,91,45.51a2,2,0,0,0-.68.13h0l0,0-.1,0C82.9,48.24,70,51.13,
                                              48.58,51.13c-20.27,0-32.93-2.59-40.37-5a2.28,2.28,0,0,0-.83-.17,2.07,2.07,0,0,0-2,1.82l0,.06,
                                              4.87,76.56c0,3.17,2.82,4.8,3.93,5.43,1.4.82,6.74,6.15,35.08,6.15s33.68-5.33,35.08-6.15c1.11-.63,
                                              3.93-2.26,3.93-5.43L93.05,47.8l0,0C93,47.72,93.05,47.65,93.05,47.59ZM48.42,80a5.59,5.59,0,1,1-5.59,
                                              5.59A5.59,5.59,0,0,1,48.42,80ZM32.24,118a5.59,5.59,0,1,1,5.59-5.59A5.59,5.59,0,0,1,32.24,118ZM34.6...
```

Now in another XAML Page I've merged my ResourceDictionary and I'm trying to draw this icon using the following code

```
<DrawingImage>
  <DrawingImage.Drawing>
    <GeometryDrawing >
      <GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
        <PathGeometry/>
      </GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
    </GeometryDrawing>
  </DrawingImage.Drawing>
</DrawingImage>
```

My intention is to use the PathGeometry that I've already defined inside my ResourceDictionary.xaml but I haven't found a way to reference this. I can't call `<PathGeometry Figures="{StaticResource myIcon}"` nor I find something like `<GeometryDrawing.Geometry Data={} />` or `<GeometryDrawing.Geometry PathGeometry={} />` that I could use to reference directly the object I'm trying to use. I've googled the topic but haven't found any answers yet.

Is there a way to reference a whole object from the resource dictionary?

Comment: As a note, you may perhaps also want to use a Path: `<Path Data="{StaticResource DeleteIcon}" Fill="Black"/>`

Comment: I would use a Path but it's not possible for me in this context. I'm using DevExpress and for the BarItem.Glyph property paths are not supported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is as simple as this:

```
<DrawingImage>
    <DrawingImage.Drawing>
        <GeometryDrawing
            Geometry="{StaticResource DeleteIcon}"
            Brush="Black" />
    </DrawingImage.Drawing>
</DrawingImage>
```

Comment: Can't believe it was right in front of me the whole time. Thanks!